# Angular2 providers automatically mock methods in every provider

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have an angular2 component that is dependent on a number of providers.  From what I have read so far in order to mock the providers I have two options

1. Write a mock service for each provider.
2. Use a spy and mock only the methods called by component.

If I go down option 1 then I have to write a lot of dummy code which is a waste of space.  If I do down option 2 then I need to have intricate knowledge of what each provider is and then write mock only the methods.  What I want to do is to mock all the methods automatically in all the providers and then write spies(custom mock logic) only when I need to.  How do I do this?

For example how do I automatically mock the following service

```
public class ActualService(){
  public getUsers(){
     //Actual call
  }

  public udpateUser(user:User){
     //Actual call to be backend to update the user
  }
}
```

how do I automatically mock everything in this to do nothing using a library like Sinon? or something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortcuts are unacceptable in unit testing because this results in low quality tests that don't fail when they should and are difficult to debug when they fail.

The preferable way is to create a new stub/mock object that has only methods that are affected by current test. When tested code is changed to introduce a method that wasn't taken into consideration in tests, this will result in failed test with clear error message.

Despite described downsides, it's possible to do this with Sinon:

```
const serviceStub = sinon.createStubInstance(Service);
```

Or with Jasmine:

```
const serviceStub = jasmine.createSpyObj('Service',
  Service.prototype.getOwnPropertyNames
  .filter(prop => typeof Service.prototype[prop] === 'function')
);

...
providers: [{ provide: Service, useValue: serviceStub }]
...
```